# How to modify my code in order to extract my output executed from code on Python terminal to a fasta file?

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, biopython, pdb-files

I am stuck on this part.
I have generated a code to make my desired sequences using Biopython.
These are my codes below.
How to I modify this code in order to have is saved as a fast file in my present working directory.

```
for record in SeqIO.parse("4N8C.pdb", "pdb-seqres"):
    print('>'+s+'_chain_'+record.annotations['chain']+'\n'+record.seq)

    >my_protein_chain_H
    QVQLQQSGPEVVRPGVSVRISCKGSGYTFTDYAMHWVKQSHAKSLDWIGVIGTDNGNTNYNQKFKGKATMTVDKSSNTAYMELGRLTSEDSAIYYCARRDRDDVWFAYWGQGTLVTVSAAKTTAPSVYPLAPVCGDTTGSSVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTLTWNSGSLSSGVHTFPAVLQSDLYTLSSSVTVTSSTWPSQSITCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIEPRGP
    >my_protein_chain_I
    QVQLQQSGPEVVRPGVSVRISCKGSGYTFTDYAMHWVKQSHAKSLDWIGVIGTDNGNTNYNQKFKGKATMTVDKSSNTAYMELGRLTSEDSAIYYCARRDRDDVWFAYWGQGTLVTVSAAKTTAPSVYPLAPVCGDTTGSSVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTLTWNSGSLSSGVHTFPAVLQSDLYTLSSSVTVTSSTWPSQSITCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIEPRGP
    >my_protein_chain_L
    DIVMSQSPSSLAVSVGEKVSMSCKSSQSLFYSSYQKDLLAWYQQKPGQSPKLLIYWASTRESGVPDRFTGSGSGTDFTLTISSVKAEDLAVYFCQQYYTYPLTFGAGTKLELKRADAAPTVSIFPPSSEQLTSGGASVVCFLNNFYPKDINVKWKIDGSERQNGVLNSWTDQDSKDSTYSMSSTLTLTKDEYERHNSYTCEATHKTSTSPIVKSFNRNEC
    >my_protein_chain_M
    DIVMSQSPSSLAVSVGEKVSMSCKSSQSLFYSSYQKDLLAWYQQKPGQSPKLLIYWASTRESGVPDRFTGSGSGTDFTLTISSVKAEDLAVYFCQQYYTYPLTFGAGTKLELKRADAAPTVSIFPPSSEQLTSGGASVVCFLNNFYPKDINVKWKIDGSERQNGVLNSWTDQDSKDSTYSMSSTLTLTKDEYERHNSYTCEATHKTSTSPIVKSFNRNEC
    >my_protein_chain_X
    MSLLTEVETPIRNEWGCRCNDSS
    >my_protein_chain_Y
    MSLLTEVETPIRNEWGCRCNDSS
```

Comment: Have you read up on [`SeqIO.write()`](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO)? There is also [this tutorial](https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec73). Which specific problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

Single fasta file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec 31 11:11:53 2020

@author: Pietro
"""


from Bio import SeqIO

pdb_file = "2ms2.pdb"

with open(pdb_file+'_fasta', "w+") as write_fasta:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(pdb_file, "pdb-seqres"):
        print('>'+record.name+'_chain_'+record.annotations['chain']+'\n'+record.seq)
        SeqIO.write(record , write_fasta , "fasta")
#        write_fasta.write('>'+record.name+'_chain_'+record.annotations['chain']+'\n'+str(record.seq)+'\n')
```

Multiple fasta files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec 31 11:11:53 2020

@author: Pietro
"""


from Bio import SeqIO

pdb_file = "4N8C.pdb"


for record in SeqIO.parse(pdb_file, "pdb-seqres"):
    print('>'+record.name+'_chain_'+record.annotations['chain']+'\n'+record.seq)
    with open(pdb_file+'_chain_'+record.annotations['chain']+'_fasta', "w+") as write_fasta:
        SeqIO.write(record , write_fasta , "fasta")
#       write_fasta.write('>'+record.name+'_chain_'+record.annotations['chain']+'\n'+str(record.seq))
```

SeqIO.write and write_fasta.write rows are equivalent but the latter print fasta sequence on single line while the former split sequences in chunks of 60 aa

write_fasta.write doesnt cointains description and maybe its not fasta compliant
('pdb:chainID_chain' istead of 'pdb:chainID _chain ...' )

Answer (score 0):

Single fasta file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec 31 11:11:53 2020

@author: Pietro
"""


from Bio import SeqIO


from Bio.PDB import PDBParser


pdb_file = "4N8C.pdb"

pdb = pdb_file.split('.')[0]

parser = PDBParser()


with open(pdb_file+'_fasta', "w+") as write_fasta:
    for record in SeqIO.PdbIO.AtomIterator(pdb, parser.get_structure(pdb ,pdb_file)):
        SeqIO.write(record , write_fasta , "fasta")
```